# AngularJS change attribute model from inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have setup a directive as below, which is to control the opening and closing of a Flyout panel, I want the state(whether its open/closed) of the flyout to be publicly accessible by the parent scope, I see some use a service for this but it seems verbose use a service, my questions is I'm wondering is there an elegant way to set the variable attached to the attribute on the Close Event? or do I have to access the parent scope? Fiddle Here http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/EbDRR/

```
<div class="page">
<button ng-click="openFlyout()">Bhttp://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/EbDRR/#baseutton {{fly.flyoutOpen}}</button>
<flyout foopen={{fly.flyoutOpen}}>
    <button ng-click="close()">X</button>
</flyout>
</div>



angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
        $scope.fly = {flyoutOpen:false};
        $scope.openFlyout = function(){
            $scope.fly.flyoutOpen = !$scope.fly.flyoutOpen;
        }
    }).directive('flyout', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, el, attr) {

            close.bind('click', function() {
               //Set fly.flyoutOpen via attr.foopen to false
            });
            attr.$observe('foopen', function(value) {        
                console.log(typeof value);
                if (value == "true") {                      
                    el.css('right', '0');
                    console.log("left:"+value);
                } else {                                   
                    el.css('right', '-150px');
                    console.log("right:"+value);
                }       
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/EbDRR/13/ ?

Comment: That's really what I'm trying to avoid, I want to keep the directive and the controller as independent as possible. i.e so if I change the name of $scope.fly.flyout to  $scope.fly.isOpen I don't need to change anything in the directive

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is not angular-way to change parent scope in directives.
Although I also have faced the situations that I could not find other solutions, I think we should avoid this way as much as possible.
In your situation, I believe you could avoid to change the parent scope in your directive.

Therefore what I suggest you is ...

1. Remove `close.bind('click'...` in your directive.
2. Add `close` function of the controller in which you could change the scope value.(as you know this way would not break the angular-principles at all.)

[jsfiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/x69n3Lk2/1/)

I hope this would help you.

Comment: My example is very simplified version of the real directive i.e. theres other functionality inside the directive that needs to change the flyout open state, and I want as much as possible of the functionality encapsulated inside the directive rather than in the controller, although the flyout also needs to be triggered by an independent directive

Comment: Ok. I could suggest another solution, if what you want to achieve is only as follows, 

1. encapsulate the features inside directive.
2. don't share the scope values with parent controller.
3. don't use services.

Anything else?

Comment: That sounds like what I'm after

Comment: I posted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.
You can can use directive scope that can use for two way binding.

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/EbDRR/14/>
```

I have added "openclose" attribute in your code.

Comment: You're going to hit a problem; with a boolean (or other scalar) your child scope is going to crush the original value, and disconnect itself from the parent-scope.  You need to have at least one dot on the child side, if you want to keep the two-way binding.  `<flyout view="page.flyout">{{ view.isOpen }} <button ng-click="view.isOpen = false">&times;</button></flyout>`

Comment: The fiddle provided maybe on the right track although how would I close the flyout from inside the directive at close.bind('click', function(){//close})

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these two examples; sorry they're both one-pagers...
I'm trying to keep the code self-contained, so that you can see the all of the pieces in one place.  Normally, there'd be build-processes keeping code and templates and the page separate; not so much, here.

The good news is that these pages should work without so much as a server (as the only external file is angular), so you can save each one as an .html page, and open it from the drive.

---

## Shared Config Between Parent and Child

```
<!doctype html>


<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      page-flyout { display: block; }
      page-flyout.expanded { background-color : grey; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main ng-controller="page-controller as page">
      <button ng-click="page.toggle()"
        >{{ page.flyout.expanded ? "Hide":"Show" }} Flyout</button>
      <page-flyout
        view="page.flyout"
        class="ng-class: {'expanded':page.flyout.expanded,'contracted':!page.flyout.expanded }"
        ></page-flyout>
    </main>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="components/page-flyout/page-flyout.html">
      <h4>I am {{ view.expanded ? "OPEN" : "CLOSED" }}</h4>
      <button ng-click="flyout.close()" ng-hide="!view.expanded">&times;</button>
    </script>
    <script >
    var app = initApp();
    initAngular(app);


    function initAngular (MyApp) {
      angular.module("myApp", ["pageFlyout"]);
      angular.module("pageFlyout", []);

      angular.module("myApp")
        .controller("MyController", [MyApp.MyController])
        .controller("page-controller", [MyApp.PageController]);

      angular.module("pageFlyout")
      .controller("page-flyout-controller", ["$scope", MyApp.PageFlyoutController])
      .directive("pageFlyout", [function () {
        return {
          scope: { view: "=" },
          restrict: "AE",
          replace: false,
          controller: "page-flyout-controller",
          controllerAs: "flyout",
          templateUrl: "components/page-flyout/page-flyout.html"
        };
      }]);
    };

    function initApp () {
      var MyApp = {
        MyController: function MyController () {

        },

        PageController: function PageController () {
          var page = extend(this, { toggle: toggle, flyout: { expanded: false } });
          function toggle () {
            var currentState = page.flyout.expanded;
            page.flyout.expanded = !currentState;
          }
        },

        PageFlyoutController: function PageFlyoutController ($scope) {
          var flyout = extend(this, { close: close });
          function close () { $scope.view.expanded = false; }
        }
      };
      function extend () {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        return angular.extend.apply(angular, args);
      }

      return MyApp;
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using a "PageController" as an outer controller; this outer element has a `toggle` method, and a `flyout` object.
The `flyout` object has an `expanded` property, and nothing more.
This is a config / state object that will be shared between the parent and child.  The parent won't know anything about the child, the child won't know anything about the parent...
But both need to know about the structure of this one object; basically, the parent has to agree to give the child a config object which meets the child's needs, if it's going to use the child's services.

In my child scope, I'm referring to this object as the `view`, which is provided in my directive declaration `<page-flyout view="page.flyout">`.

The flyout has a controller, with a `close` method, which sets `view.expanded = false;` 
Because the parent and the child both share this config object, and because a UI event triggers a check for digest, this works and everybody's happy...

Try it out, and see what happens: the flyout html is in a completely different universe, and yet the button still does what it should, and all of the text inside and outside of the flyout's scope keeps itself up to date...

...except that this isn't quite as clean as could be.

Sharing some sort of readable state would be one thing, but two people directly writing to it, and reading from it, might be a bit much.

---

## Parent Controls State, Child Defines Event, Parent Implements Event-Handler

```
<!doctype html>


<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      page-flyout { display: block; }
      page-flyout.expanded { background-color : grey; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main ng-controller="page-controller as page">
      <button ng-click="page.toggle()"
        >{{ page.flyout.expanded ? "Hide":"Show" }} Flyout</button>
      <page-flyout
        onclose="page.close()"
        class="ng-class: {'expanded':page.flyout.expanded,'contracted':!page.flyout.expanded }"
        ></page-flyout>
    </main>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="components/page-flyout/page-flyout.html">
      <h4>I am {{ view.expanded ? "OPEN" : "CLOSED" }}</h4>
      <button ng-click="flyout.close()">&times;</button>
    </script>
    <script >
    var app = initApp();
    initAngular(app);


    function initAngular (MyApp) {
      angular.module("myApp", ["pageFlyout"]);
      angular.module("pageFlyout", []);

      angular.module("myApp")
        .controller("MyController", [MyApp.MyController])
        .controller("page-controller", [MyApp.PageController]);

      angular.module("pageFlyout")
      .controller("page-flyout-controller", ["$scope", MyApp.PageFlyoutController])
      .directive("pageFlyout", [function () {
        return {
          scope: { onclose: "&" },
          restrict: "AE",
          replace: false,
          controller: "page-flyout-controller",
          controllerAs: "flyout",
          templateUrl: "components/page-flyout/page-flyout.html"
        };
      }]);
    };

    function initApp () {
      var MyApp = {
        MyController: function MyController () {

        },

        PageController: function PageController () {
          var page = extend(this, {
            toggle: toggle,
            close: close,
            flyout: { expanded: false }
          });

          function toggle () {
            var currentState = page.flyout.expanded;
            page.flyout.expanded = !currentState;
          }
          function close () {
            page.flyout.expanded = false;
          }
        },

        PageFlyoutController: function PageFlyoutController ($scope) {
          var flyout = extend(this, { close: close });
          function close () { $scope.onclose(); }
        }
      };
      function extend () {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        return angular.extend.apply(angular, args);
      }

      return MyApp;
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'll save you some hunting; almost every single line here is 100% the same.
The important ones are in the directive:

```
return {
  scope: { onclose: "&" }
}
```

...the ampersand means that the property `$scope.onclose` is a method, which is defined on declaration of the directive.

Sure enough, when you look at the declaration of `page-flyout`, you'll notice `<page-flyout onclose="page.close()">`

Now $scope.onclose doesn't equal `page.close();` so much as it equals `function () { page.close(); }`.
It could, instead be a simple expression, inside of the scope of the parent:

```
<page-flyout onclose="page.flyout.expanded = false">
$scope.onclose = function () { page.flyout.expanded = false; };
```

You can even pass named params back into your parent expression/method (unnecessary here; read up on it in tutorials, but basically you call `$scope.method( paramsObj )` where the keys of the object are the same as the argument names in the implementation.  Really handy stuff.

So in my case, my flyout button calls `flyout.close()`, a method on my controller.  My controller method calls `$scope.onclose();` (a separation between my viewmodel stuff, and the angular-specific glue that ties everything together), `$scope.onclose` then calls `page.close()` in the parent, which sets `page.flyout.expanded = false;`.

Nice. Neat. Clean.

The child knows absolutely nothing about the parent, and yet, I created an event that the parent could subscribe to; in HTML, no less.

One **big** problem, though.
If you load this page up, you'll notice that the flyout's text never changes, and the close button for the flyout never hides itself, based on whether the flyout is "open" or "closed".
The reason for that is dirt-simple.
The child knows absolutely nothing about the parent or the parent's data.

That's fine, but in this case, that means despite being able to close itself just fine, it can never know if it's open in the first place (if I used `ng-hide` in the parent scope, that would solve the problem, if you didn't want to leave it half-open).

The solution, of course, is to give the child a shared object, representing the state of a flyout...
We've been there before...
...except that this time, it's a read-only object (no guarantees, just by practice), and you're using events to talk up, and using properties to talk down.

The real solution involves doing both: having both the read-only properties for the child to use in its view, and to create events that the parent can hook into, to update its model (and what it gives back to the child on the next $digest).

Then aside from the contract the child defines and the parent keeps, neither one knows anything about the other.

Comment: Yes this looks like it would work, although the functionality of the directive is now in the controller/page which renders the directive almost pointless other than to allow you to reuse the template, which is not what I'm after

Comment: Alternatively, if the only thing the whole directive is doing is controlling the CSS positioning, that could be resolved with one boolean and one `ng-style` attribute. The separation that's gained here allows the outer world to control the positioning and the configuration, while allowing the inner world to encapsulate its internal workings.  It just so happens that you have no internals.  You could have a list of items which close the menu when selected, or open sub-lists. You could have a dozen extended events or just one. But CSS on the container is appropriate for position-only requirement

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to achieve is as follows.

1. encapsulate the features inside directive.
2. don't share the scope values with parent controller.
3. don't use services.

My idea is something like this.

1. Prepare the function which is the wrapper for updating the element of your flyout panel.(**This function is completely encapsulated only in the directive.**)
2. Instanciate the wrapper and use it in your directive code **independently**.
3. After instanciating the wrapper, the directive send it via `oninit` function to a parent controller.
4. After recieveing the wrapper, the controller could use it **without sharing the scope**.

[jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/x69n3Lk2/6/)

Comment: I've not seen a directive structured like this before (instanced with the new operator rather than in the Link) I will do some research and come back to this, Thanx

Comment: I'm looking forward to it. enjoy!  :)